# Add select options dynamically to admin form in magento2

Tags: magento2, adminform, select, option

I have created a model.

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'test1',
        'text',
        array(
            'name' => 'test1',
            'label' => __('Test 1'),
            'title' => __('Test 1'),
            /*'required' => true,*/
        )
    );

  $fieldset->addField(
        "test2",
        "select",
        [
            "label"     =>      __("Test 2"),
            "name"      =>      "test2",
            "values"    =>      [
                ["value" => 1,"label" => __("Option 1")],
                ["value" => 2,"label" => __("Option 2")],
                ["value" => 3,"label" => __("Option 3")],
                ["value" => 4,"label" => __("Option 4")],
                ["value" => 5,"label" => __("Option 5")],
            ]
        ]
    );
```

This is working well, but i need to add the option values dynamically, that is i need to get the result from one of the custom table and add them as values.

my custom table have the record like below.

```
  table custom_table;

  id   options

  1   Option 1

  2   Option 2

  3   Option 3

  4   Option 4

  5   Option 5
```

How to read this table and add the result as value for my admin form field there.

Can anyone look into this and update me your ideas please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a recommended way but I think you can write a **custom Mysql Query (Without Using Model)**.

You can try like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('custom_table'); 

//Select Data from custom_table
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

And you can loop the **result** in your **select field options** like this:

```
foreach($result as $key => $option){
      $options[] = ["value" => $key,"label" => __($option)],
}

$fieldset->addField(
     "test2",
     "select",
     [
         "label"     =>      __("Test 2"),
         "name"      =>      "test2",
         "values"    =>    [$options]
     ]
 );
```

Adding here: [Fetch database custom table using custom model and Resourcemodel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236114/fetch-data-from-database-custom-table?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: facing syntax error,Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ']'

Comment: this is not working, i hope there is no any syntax errors

Comment: @jafarpinjar try updated answer

Comment: ,Undefined index: value in vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Select.php getting below error

Comment: oh I cant really check now as Im using mobile only. tomorrow I can check when in office

Comment: sure @magefrms . thank you

Comment: @jafarpinjar can you print_r('$result') and check what you got

Comment: @magefrms, i resolved this one myself, thanks for the help

Comment: if you can please check and help on this issue,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276331/multiselect-form-field-not-saved-to-database-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer

```
foreach($result as $key => $option){
      $options[] = ["value" => $key,"label" => __($option)],
}

    $fieldset->addField(
         "test2",
         "select",
         [
             "label"     =>      __("Test 2"),
             "name"      =>      "test2",
             "values"    =>    $options
         ]
     );
```