# multiselect form field not saved to database in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminform, select

I have created a custom admin form.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'core_units',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'name' => 'core_units[]',
            'label' => __('Select Core units'),
            'title' => __('Select Core units'),
            'class' => 'core_units',
            'values' => [
                         ["value" => 1,"label" => __("Option 1")],
                        ["value" => 2,"label" => __("Option 2")],
                      ["value" => 3,"label" => __("Option 3")],
                     ["value" => 4,"label" => __("Option 4")],
                      ["value" => 5,"label" => __("Option 5")],
                       ]
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
    'optional_units',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'name' => 'optional_units[]',
            'label' => __('Select Optional units'),
            'title' => __('Select Optional units'),
            'class' => 'optional_units',
            'values' => [
            ["value" => 1,"label" => __("Option 1")],
            ["value" => 2,"label" => __("Option 2")],
            ["value" => 3,"label" => __("Option 3")],
            ["value" => 4,"label" => __("Option 4")],
            ["value" => 5,"label" => __("Option 5")],
                        ]
        ]
    );
```

Here is my Save controller file code.

```
class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

public function execute()
{

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if ($data) {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('X247commerce\Qualbuilder\Model\Qualbuilder');

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
        }

        $model->setData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Frist Grid Has been Saved.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Model\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the banner.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('banner_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id')));
        return;
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
   }
}
```

The above code showing the multi select drop down in the form, but whenever options selected and saved, its not getting saved to database.

I am posting the controller data.

```
 Array
(
 [key] => 4317ff2ff34444a61eac0c70b0502924318cb0465c3c7244b0e59eef5c593059

[form_key] => ndLnj7PmwQfgbKYG
[core_units] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
    )

[optional_units] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
    )
```

)

If same row re-opened again. the options are non selected.

can anyone look into this and update me your thoughts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add your save controller

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, updated, please check once

Comment: Are you getting multiple ids in $data for multiple select filed? have you checked?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, yes i am getting as array for those fields

Comment: check if you have data passed in your $data , try print_r($data); and check what data is passed

Comment: @magefms, updated print_r($data) into question

Comment: you are supposed to get the `[0] => 1
        [1] => 3` right?

Comment: @magefms, no I have selected two options for each drop down and printed here, but its not storing to db, how multi-select options get stored to db

Comment: your code seems to be good until the `$model->setData($data);` I think you are not supposed to pass all data to model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Change Your Field Name :-**

**From :-**

```
'name' => 'core_units[]'
```

**To :-**

```
'name' => 'core_units'
```

> **And Also 2nd Field :-**

**From :-**

```
'name' => 'optional_units[]',
```

**To :-**

```
'name' => 'optional_units',
```

**In Controller :-**

```
$data['core_units']=implode(',',$data['core_units']);
$data['optional_units']=implode(',',$data['optional_units']);
$model->setData($data);
```

Comment: hi @Rathod, No its not getting saved, i am getting the exception after this change,the exception is,Exception message: Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: in controller check $data

Comment: and save that field data as per array format

Comment: i posted the controller data into the question, can you please updated it, how can i change the code there.

Comment: please add output of $data after apply my code

Comment: yes, its after applying your code..

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94189/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rk-rathod).